# If $p$ is a natural prime number and if $a$ is an integer such that $1 < a < p$, prove that $p$ divides $\binom{p}{a}$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients, divisibility

If $p$ is a natural prime number and if $a$ is an integer such that $1 < a < p$, prove that $p$ divides $\binom{p}{a}$.

Reminder: $$\dbinom{p}{a}=\frac{p(p-1)\cdots(p-a+1)}{a!}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$a\cdot {p\choose a}=p\cdot {p-1\choose a-1}$$

so $$p\mid a\cdot {p\choose a}$$ 
and since $a,p$ are relatively prime we have, by Euclid lemma $$p\mid {p\choose a}$$

Comment: Straightforward. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The numerator is divisible by $p$, the denominator not.